# Angular2 i18n for placeholder text

Tags: angular, input, internationalization, placeholder

Is there a way to translate the placeholder text for an input text field using Angular 2's i18n?

`<input placeholder="hello world" i18n>`

I don't see anything in the documentation about this: 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There has been an example, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

You should be able to use `i18n-attributename`. For example:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="From" i18n-placeholder="From placeholder"/>
```

That would need an entry like this:

```
<trans-unit id="generatedId" datatype="html">
  <source>From</source>
  <target state="translated">Van</target>
  <note priority="1" from="description">From placeholder</note>
</trans-unit>
```

In your messages.xlf file. I couldn't get it to work without a translation though. So you will need to add the state=translated and a value.

Even if we don't give value in **i18n-placeholder** then it is also fine.
just do like:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="From" i18n-placeholder/>
```

it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realized you need both _i18n-placeholder_ AND _placeholder_ for it to work.

Comment: It has been in the documentation pull-request for a while, but I couldn't find it anymore .. glad it works!

Comment: Is anyone help to sort this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57369486/angular8-i18n-for-placeholderlabel-text

Answer (score 7):

To add to the answer from @evandongen, here's where this is documented in the Angular docs:

***Updated link:***

https://angular.io/guide/i18n#translate-attributes

> **Add i18n translation attributes**
>
> ---
>
> To mark an attribute for translation, add an attribute in the form of
>   i18n-x, where x is the name of the attribute to translate. The
>   following example shows how to mark the title attribute for
>   translation by adding the i18n-title attribute on the img tag:
>
> `<img [src]="logo" i18n-title title="Angular logo" />`
>
> This technique works for any attribute of *any* element.
>
> You also can assign a meaning, description, and id with the
>   `i18n-x="<meaning>|<description>@@<id>"` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I used this attributes

```
 <input type="submit" value="{{ 'LOGIN.LOG' | translate }}">
```

Comment: Isn't this ngx-translate?