# How to translate attributes with the Angular 2 ng-xi18n tool

Tags: angular, internationalization

A tag's text can be set for translation like this:
`<h1 i18n>Welcome</h1>`

How are attributes like *placeholder* or *label* set?
`<input type="text" placeholder="Type your name" />` or
`<button type="submit" label="Send data"></button>` (library primeng requires to set the button's label like this)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 i18n for placeholder text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339109/angular2-i18n-for-placeholder-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To translate tag the `placeholder` attribute for translation you can add an `i18n-placeholder` attribute, like so:

```
<input type="text" i18n-placeholder="@@type-your-name" placeholder="Type your name" />
```

For other attributes it works the same way: `i18n-x`, where `x` is the name of the attribute to translate.

You can find the answer also inside the Angular i18n guide found [here](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#translate-attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can suggest you a great lib for that ng2-translate its very easy to use.
https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate