# Angular8 i18n for placeholderLabel text

Tags: angular-material2, angular8

How to add i18n in ngx-mat-select-search palceholderLabel

```
       <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-lg-5 mb-4">
              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width w-100">
                <mat-select (selectionChange)='vehicle_maker_updated($event)' formControlName="vehicleMakerValue" placeholder="Motor Make" i18n-placeholder>
                  <mat-option>
                    <ngx-mat-select-search formControlName="vehicleMakerFilterInputValue" placeholder="Select Motor Maker" [noEntriesFoundLabel]="'No matching vehicle makers found'" (ngModelChange)='filter_vehicle_makers($event)' i18n-placeholder></ngx-mat-select-search>
                  </mat-option>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let vehicle_maker_option of filtered_vehicle_maker_options" [value]="vehicle_maker_option.id">
                    {{vehicle_maker_option.name}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
                <mat-error *ngIf="vehicleMakerValue.hasError('required')" i18n>
                  Select motor make
                </mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>                 
          </div>
```

i have already added the i18n-placeholder but its not working

Comment: what exactly is not working? what is the result you get?

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the `placeholderLabel` attribute (see https://github.com/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search#inputs)

```html
<ngx-mat-select-search 
formControlName="vehicleMakerFilterInputValue" 
placeholderLabel="Select Motor Maker" 
[noEntriesFoundLabel]="'No matching vehicle makers found'" 
(ngModelChange)='filter_vehicle_makers($event)' 
i18n-placeholderLabel>
</ngx-mat-select-search>
```

where the `placeholderLabel` and `i18n-placeholderLabel` attributes are relevant

Comment: did you make sure you added both, the `placeholderLabel` and the `i18n-placeholderLabel` attributes?

Comment: thanks for the update. while adding it issue is fixed